# Can I change a file's modification or creation date on iOS?

Tags: ios, file-io, nsfilemanager, file-manager

I'm writing some unit tests for some file sync code I'm writing, and I'm wondering if it's possible (likely via `FileManager` but who knows) to change a file's creation / modification date *to something earlier* than its current date.  Or even if I can specify the creation date when I create a new file.

It would be nice to be able to do this programmatically inside my tests if possible, but otherwise I'm interested in if it can be done at all.

I suppose as long as it works on the iOS Simulator, that's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the modification date by running `touch -t <date> <file>`, where `<date>` is the new date and `<file>` is the file you want to modify. See the man page for `touch` for the date format, but it's basically like `YYYYMMDDhhmm.SS` (year, month, day, hour, minute, second).

Example:

```
$ touch -t 197501020304.05 foo
$ ls -lT foo
-rw-r--r--  1 userid  staff  0 Jan  2 03:04:05 1975 foo
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager), it looks like you can also set the modification date using `NSFileManager`'s [`setAttributes(_:ofItemAtPath:)` method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1413667-setattributes), which lets you set attributes for a given file, including `creationDate` and `modificationDate`. However, note that:

> *As in the POSIX standard, the app either must own the file or directory or must be running as superuser for attribute changes to take effect.*